# Behaviour of RealDigits expected or wrong?

Tags: list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy, number-representation

Is this behavior expected or a bug?

```
RealDigits[10304.390456]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 5}
> ```

when I expected

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 5}
> ```

17 significant figures doesn't make a difference as I would have expected considering that `$MachinePrecision->15.9546`.

```
RealDigits[10304.390456000000]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 5}
> ```

This is far from a the limit of machine-precision number representation.

```
RealDigits[10304.390456000000 + 10^3 $MachineEpsilon]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 5}
> ```

18 significant figures does make a difference

```
RealDigits[10304.3904560000000]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 5}
> ```

Comment: You implicitly changed a decimal fraction to binary, and then explicitly changed it back to decimal.

Comment: @JohnDoty wholdn't that give me an error of only `$MachineEpsilon` i.e around `2.22045*10^-16`? This is three orders of magnitude bigger!

Comment: Expect errors of around x*$MachineEpsilon, where x is the number in question.

Comment: OK, my bad then.

Comment: the change in the last case is because you supplied enough digits to force an extended precision representation. `ByteCount[10304.390456000000]->16` ... `ByteCount[10304.3904560000000]-> 80 `

Comment: @george2079 I see that, but I was under the impression that 16 bit would be enough to represent a number with 11 significant figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the result you are seeing gives the real digits of *Mathematica*'s internal representation of your decimal input and is, therefore, not a bug.

Perhaps you will find the following an acceptable work-around for the behavior that is bothering you.

```
RealDigits[SetPrecision[10304.390456, Floor @ $MachinePrecision]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 5}
> ```

This should work for any machine precision real.